# Probability of selecting the winning numbers in a lottery

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've been studying combinatorics for a while. I've solved a problem but I'm not sure if I'm right. I'll just copy-paste the problem here.

> In a lottery, six distinct numbers are selected at random from the set $1, \ldots, 50$ and designated as winning numbers. A player selects six distinct numbers in advance, hoping to include as many winners as possible. Find the probability that the player selects exactly $k$ winning numbers, for each $k$ from $0$ to $6$.

Here's my solution.

The probability of selecting one winning number is $\frac{\binom{6}{1}\cdot\binom{49}{5}}{\binom{50}{6}}$. And the probabilities of selecting 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 winning numbers are $\frac{\binom{6}{2}\cdot\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{50}{6}}$, $\frac{\binom{6}{3}\cdot\binom{47}{3}}{\binom{50}{6}}$, $\frac{\binom{6}{4}\cdot\binom{46}{2}}{\binom{50}{6}}$, $\frac{\binom{6}{5}\cdot\binom{45}{1}}{\binom{50}{6}}$, and $\frac{1}{\binom{50}{6}}$ respectively. So the probability of selecting 0 winning number is

$1 - \left( \frac{\binom{6}{1}\cdot\binom{49}{5}}{\binom{50}{6}} + \frac{\binom{6}{2}\cdot\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{50}{6}} + \frac{\binom{6}{3}\cdot\binom{47}{3}}{\binom{50}{6}} + \frac{\binom{6}{4}\cdot\binom{46}{2}}{\binom{50}{6}} + \frac{\binom{6}{5}\cdot\binom{45}{1}}{\binom{50}{6}} + \frac{1}{\binom{50}{6}}\right)$

Am I wrong?

Comment: If you solved it, could you include your solution so we can tell if you're right?

Comment: I think for 1 win you should have 44C5 not 49C5 since you want to know how may different combination of 5 other number are there other than the numbers you chose.

Comment: @kamster, Oh yes! Now I understand it! thank you!

Comment: @Kamster yea he needs to make this correction for all k. The probability of winning $k$ out of $m$ balls with numbers $1,2,...,n$ is $\tfrac{{m \choose k} {n-m \choose m-k}}{{n \choose m}}$ which counts $\tfrac{\text{winning tickets}}{\text{all tickets}}$.

Comment: Note that the distribution here is called a Hypergeometric Distribution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just so this one doesn't stay unanswered, as Kamster says the chance of one winning number is $\frac{\binom{6}{1}\cdot\binom{44}{5}}{\binom{50}{6}}$ because when you choose the non-winning numbers there are only $44$ of them to choose.  Once you adjust your other answers with this in mind you will be correct.